# TypeError: Failed to construct 'Headers': Invalid name

Tags: api, vue.js, get, http-headers, typeerror

I'am trying to do a get request to get all order from an API, but i get the next error: TypeError:client.js?06a0:96 TypeError: Failed to construct 'Headers': Invalid name. My code is:

```
const myHeaders = new Headers({
      "content-type" : "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
      "headers" :  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*",
      "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With",
      "Authorization " : "Bearer, mytoken"
      });
      const getSalesUrl = "myurl"
      fetch(getSalesUrl, myHeaders)
        .then(response => response.json())
        .then(json => console.log(json))
    },       `

I don't know what i'am doing wrong can any one tell me?
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you need to instantiate a Headers with the fetch library, this should be sufficient.

```js
const myHeaders = {
    "content-type": "application/x-www-form-urlencoded",
    "headers": "Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*",
    "Access-Control-Allow-Headers": "Origin, X-Requested-With",
    "Authorization ": "Bearer, mytoken"
};
```

Comment: hey thanks for you're response now i get the following error: Uncaught (in promise) TypeError: Failed to execute 'fetch' on 'Window': The provided value is not of type '(sequence<sequence<ByteString>> or record<ByteString, ByteString>)

Comment: I don't know if you know what the problem for this can be?